# Different implementations of inline functions in different translation units

Tags: c++, inline, language-lawyer

The C++ standard says this about ODR, as it applies to inline functions (emphasis mine):

> **3.2 One definition rule**
>
> 3 Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used**.

It doesn't say anything about whether the inline functions can have different implementations in different translation units. I tried the following:

**test-1.cc**

```
#include <iostream> 
inline std::ostream& foo(std::ostream& os)
{
   return os << "Foo_1";
}

void test_1()
{
   foo(std::cout) << std::endl;
}
```

**test-2.cc**

```
#include <iostream> 
inline std::ostream& foo(std::ostream& os)
{
   return os << "Foo_2";
}

void test_2()
{
   foo(std::cout) << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cc**

```
extern void test_1();
extern void test_2();

int main()
{
   test_1();
   test_2();
   return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to see the following output:

```
Foo_1
Foo_2
```

Instead, I saw:

```
Foo_1
Foo_1
```

I tested it using `g++ 4.7.3`.

Is g++ correct in choosing to pick one of the inline implementations? Is it not possible to provide different implementations of inline functions in different translation units?

Comment: It's strongly supposed that the functions you wrote are not inlined. As the key word `inline` is just a hint or suggestion, a compiler would generate non-inlined code. How about examining the generated binary to verify? Also with `-O2` both `g++` and `clang++` gives expected output with `Foo_2`

Comment: Referring to my answer below there is no expected output since this is undefined behaviour according to the standard.

Comment: If you want to do this make the functions `static` or place them in an unnamed namespace.

Comment: In practical terms, the linker picks one of the multiple instances of a function with the same name. Probably the first one it saw. OTOH, as everyone has pointed out, you are in undefined behavior land, so anything is possible, even fairy unicorns riding rainbow dinosaurs down your block.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I am aware of those options. I was just exploring the nature of what the standard says about inline functions with external linkage. I find the job of navigating the standard challenging at times, and fascinating after I find all the pieces that fit together in a sensible way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ISO C++ 2003 § 3.2 paragraph 5 says

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function
>   with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.5), static data
>   member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template special-
>   ization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.4) in a program provided that each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following require-
>   ments. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - **each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens**
> - (more requirements follow)
>
> ...
>
> If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

So, no, non-equivalent definitions are illegal. Since the behaviour is undefined the compiler is pretty much free to do anything, including picking his favorite implementation and ignoring others.

Answer (score 4):

You need to finish reading that subclause. §3.2 [basic.def.odr]/p6 documents the requirements for multiple definitions of inline functions with external linkage. The whole list of requirements with half a dozen items occupies a whole page, but basically boils down to "they must have exactly the same sequence of tokens and mean exactly the same thing".

In your case the multiple definitions of `foo` don't even satisfy the first requirement - that the definitions consist of the same sequence of tokens. Undefined behavior results.

Answer (score -1):

There is no explicit statement in the standard that says that an inline function should have one, and only one implementation body. 
Of course, in production code, you have to make sure there's only one body .. imagine the debugging/maintenance fiasco if you have to work with code like the one you give in example !

This is obviously not code you would run in production ; I hear you, you are curious about the language.

Because the standard is not explicit, this leads to a gray area and compilers do whatever they want.
Actually, Stroustrup himself wrote in 1994 in "Design & Evolution of C++" that *most compilers don't check for this* , and this situation hasn't improved to this day !

Comment: The inline function need not have one implementation body but the other answers clearly cite the standard where it says that the inline implementations *must have exactly the same sequence of tokens and mean exactly the same thing.*

Comment: Sorry R Sahu, but the 2 previous answers are not actually correct, according to www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf , §3.2 "One Definition Rule", 3rd bullet: "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used" . There is no mention of whether the definitions need to be the same. That's the point Stroustrup brought up in his book. The answer by T.C. is not correct because 'the requirement that each definition shall consist of the same sequence of tokens' applies to inline functions with *external linkage* which is not the case here.

Comment: Why do think these inline functions don't have external linkage?

Comment: inline does not imply internal linkage.