# One definition rule and template class specializations

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming, cppunit

The authors of a [popular library](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppunit) decided to implement [the following design pattern](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppunit/code/HEAD/tree/tags/REL_1_10_2/cppunit/include/cppunit/TestAssert.h#l36):

```
// my_traits.hpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

template<typename T>
struct my_traits {
        static bool equals(const T& x, const T& y) {
                printf("base\n");
                return x == y;
        }
};

template<typename T>
void my_assert(const T& x, const T& y) {
        assert(my_traits<T>::equals(x, y));
}
```

Now assume that the library is used as follows:

```
// main.cpp
void my_test1();
void my_test2();

int main() {
        my_test1();
        my_test2();
        return 0;
}
```

and

```
// my_test1.cpp
#include "my_traits.hpp"

void my_test1() {
        my_assert(-1.0, -1.0);
}
```

and

```
//my_test2.cpp
#include "my_traits.hpp"

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <float.h>
#define isnan _isnan
#else
#include <math.h>
#endif

template<>
struct my_traits<double> {
        static bool equals(const double& x, const double& y) {
                printf("specialization\n");
                return x == y || isnan(x) && isnan(y);
        }
};

void my_test2() {
        my_assert(-1.0, -1.0);
}
```

Now,

```
$ g++ main.cpp my_test1.cpp my_test2.cpp && ./a.out
base
base
```

whereas

```
$ g++ main.cpp my_test2.cpp my_test1.cpp && ./a.out
specialization
specialization
```

The user of the library would, of course, desire to obtain the following result irrespective of link order:

```
base
specialization
```

Short of specializing or overloading (inlined) `my_assert` instead of `my_traits`, and knowing that injecting the same specialization into every translation unit where `my_traits.hpp` is included is not acceptable (or maintainable), **can anyone think of another trick that achieves the desired behaviour without modifying `my_traits.hpp` or specializing `my_assert`** (or using a kludgy wrapper class for `double` :) )?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241023/different-implementations-of-inline-functions-in-different-translation-units

Comment: "knowing that injecting the same specialization into every translation unit where my_traits.hpp is included is not acceptable (or maintainable)" - you can't accept or maintain a header file with the single-line declaration `template<> struct my_traits<double>;` in it?

Comment: @casey, re. (1) acceptability: users may have a valid need to be able to e.g. treat `NaN`'s as "equal" in one unit test, but different in another (I believe this could have been easily addressed via e.g. overloading had the library in question defined `equals` as a function template, or had C++ supported specializations in namespaces other than the base template's namespace);

Comment: @casey, re. (2) maintainability issue, assuming that (1) above is not an issue, then how does one enforce §14.7.3 quoted below, i.e. that one year down the road Joe Shmoe will not `#include <my_traits.hpp>` (straight from the library) without declaring the specialization, while instantiating `my_traits<double>`, thus altering the behaviour of the other translation units?

Answer (score 6):

§14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p6 (emphasis added):

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then **that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs**; no diagnostic is required. If the program
>   does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and
>   either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member
>   function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: The question is not "why the observed behaviour?", I think the "why" was relatively clear to begin with. :)

Comment: @vladr And it should be obvious that there's no standard-compliant way for calls to the same specialization of `my_assert` to produce different results in different translation units in the same program.

Comment: Where did the question limit the solution gamut to template specializations?  For instance, the question already mentions one possible solution (wrapper classes for double, which _can_ produce different results in different translation units without any specialization of `my_template` whatsoever), surely there must be other tricks (*overloading* `my_assert` is another one that jumps to mind).